# Expression to Simulink Model Conversion

Tags: matlab, scripting, simulink

The input will be a string (eg.'X+Y+Z') and the output must be a Simulink Model(slx file). This should be done using m-script. The Simulink Model should be dynamic(the model must be according to the input expression provided - if input expression changes, the model generated must be corresponding to the input expression. The X,Y,Z are the constant blocks with values X,Y,Z respectively.

Assumptions -
->The variables are X, Y and Z only. The operators can be any of the following(+,-,*,/).
->Implement the Multiplication operator using Product Block.
->No coefficients are present for the X,Y,Z variables.

My Approach - I used RegExp to extract the terms and operators. All the terms(X,Y,Z) are present in 'terms' cell array and operators are obtained in the 'operators' cell array.

Next, I thought of using the 'Stack' concept to solve this problem. I first stored the terms(X,Y,Z) in the stack in reverse order of their occurence in the expression. Then, I used the top 2 terms in the stack to create their respective Add Blocks. For this I have used the 'add_block' function. But I m unable to give the unique names to these blocks, as the block names must be unique.

And, I am unable to connect these constant blocks to the Add Block.

I am stuck at this position. Please provide me the best and optimized approach to solve this problem.

Comment: Please share your code so that we can see where the issue is. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I have written the code and it worked! Thank You.

Comment: I have also added the the coefficients in the expression. The input string is in the form of '3x+4y-10z'.

Comment: perfect then! if the query is solved, accept the answer and if you have new ones create new questions as it is the standard procedure instead of appending them here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make a name unique while programmatically adding blocks to to a simulink model there is a name-value field in the `add_block`. Please refer to [add_block documentation](https://ch.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/add_block.html):

> `h = add_block(source,dest,'MakeNameUnique','on')` ensures that the
> destination block name is unique in the model. This syntax adds a
> number to the destination block name if a block with that name exists,
> incrementing to ensure a unique name.

so:

```
add_block('Simulink/Math Operations/Sum','<yourprojectname>/<nonuniquename>','MakeNameUnique','on')
```

---

Otherwise, since you are not blindly generating but the structure and number of blocks is known you could set the name of the block upon creation with the `add_block` **dest** field iself:

```
add_block('Simulink/Math Operations/Sum','<yourprojectname>/<uniquename>');
```

so for example:

```
add_block('Simulink/Math Operations/Sum','<yourprojectname>/XYaddition');
add_block('Simulink/Math Operations/Sum','<yourprojectname>/XYaddition');
```